# deliver an array (type: var) to an _Click-event in C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm getting really frustrated as I'm trying to get an array to my _Click-Event in my ASP.NET-Application.

Here's the thing:
I have an dynamicly created "form", which is a todolist.
So for every todo, I have an description (from the database), a note-field and a checkbox.

Since their could be 0-n todos, I can't work with the asp:-Tag in the ascx-File.

That's why I created an class for each todo, which looks like this:

```
private class todoContainer 
    { 
        public int? id 
        { 
            get; 
            set; 
        } 

        public CheckBox activeted 
        { 
            get; 
            set; 
        }
[...]
```

The list gets created with an foreach-loop and every toDo goes into the array "todoArray".
Here's how I work with the Controls inide the loop:
    checkboxArea.Controls.Add(todoArray[todoArrayInt].activeted);

Since I now want to send the list to the submit-event with all the changes I made (for examples if I want to add a note to toDo X and want to cross off toDo Y), I have to get the whole array in my _Click-method.
Unfortunately I can't find a way to accomplish this...

I tried this:

- Get the whole array into an asp:HiddenField-Controll, which doesn't work at all
- Get the array into a session, but than I can't find a way how to track changes...

If anybody could help me, I would be realy thankfull.

Best regards
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about using a asp:repeater control?

on your submit button click event you should be able to loop through every item in your asp:repeater

> foreach(RepeaterItem item in repeater1.Items)
>                 {
>
> ```
>              TextBox box = (TextBox)item.FindControl("Value");
>              string b = box.Text;               
>
>            }
> ```
>
> //do stuff here after looping through repeater

Answer (score 1):

If you need a collection of checkboxes each one associated with a different TODO, try using a CheckBoxList control.

[CheckBoxList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx)

Using this control you can associate each TODO in your array (no need to store a reference to the checkbox) with a checkbox item using the Value property of each item to store the id.

Retrieving the TODO's again in the onclick event would be as simple as iterating over the CheckBoxList Items collection (CheckBoxes) and checking the Value property to determine which CheckBox belonged to which TODO.